# Disable weekends and specific dates jQueryUI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to disable weekends in the datepicker, as well as specific dates which will be in an array. I've noticed I cannot combine these 2 options in `beforeShowDay` as it only accepts 1 function. Is there a way I can add 2 function in `beforeShowDay`?

```js
$(function() {
  var unavailableDates = ["27-12-2021", "28-12-2021", "29-12-2021", "30-12-2021", "31-12-2021", "01-01-2022", "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022", "04-01-2022"];

  function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
      return [true, ""];
    } else {
      return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
  }

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    minDate: '10D',
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, unavailable // throws an error becaus ei have 2 options
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: Note that if this is throwing an error I'd suggest you update your browser. While the code won't work, the syntax you're using is valid in ES6, which is supported in all modern browsers. I would assume you're using IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `beforeShowDay` property only accepts a single function.

To do what you require you can create an anonymous function where you call both `noWeekends()` and your `unavailable()` functions and combine the result, like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let unavailableDates = ["27-12-2021", "28-12-2021", "29-12-2021", "30-12-2021", "31-12-2021", "01-01-2022", "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022", "04-01-2022"];
  let isUnavailable = date => $.inArray(`${date.getDate()}-${(date.getMonth() + 1)}-${date.getFullYear()}`, unavailableDates) >= 0;

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    minDate: '10D',
    beforeShowDay: date => {
      if (isUnavailable(date) || !$.datepicker.noWeekends(date)[0]) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
      } else {
        return [true, ""];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: i see - from the snippet i cans ee that the weekends are still being displayed?

Comment: Apologies - I've corrected the answer.